# Schema from drf-yasg for nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi, drf-yasg

I built nested serializer where ModelSerializer include another serializer as field. Everything works well but in swagger docs in example body parameters I don't see openning_time field. What can I change to obtain openning_time field in docs? I tried with swagger_auto_schema but got error:

*drf_yasg.errors.SwaggerGenerationError: specify the body parameter as a Schema or Serializer in request_body*

**serializers.py**

```
class WarehouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    openning_time = OpenningTimeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = ['pk', 'name', 'action_available', 'openning_time', 'workers']
```

**views.py**

```
class WarehouseApi(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                mixins.ListModelMixin,
                viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = Warehouse.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WarehouseSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    warehouse_param_config = openapi.Parameter(
        'openning_time', in_=openapi.IN_BODY, description='Description', type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT)

    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[warehouse_param_config])
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

There is screen from swagger docs and i wanted add information about openning_time which is represented as list of dictionaries as below:

```
    [
    {
        "weekday": 4,
        "from_hour": "12:22:00",
        "to_hour": "13:13:00"
    },
    {
        "weekday": 5,
        "from_hour": "16:00:00",
        "to_hour": "23:00:00"
    }
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use decorator like

```
@swagger_auto_schema(request_body=WarehouseSerializer)
```

refer documentation
[Custom schema generation](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html)